# i need solution for imread

Tags: image, matlab, using

i want to load my image call caltrain, there is 30 img.
i used code

for i = 0:30

```
imgINumber = i;
imgPNumber = i+2;
if imgINumber < 10
    imgIFile = sprintf('C:\sequence01_caltrain_gray\caltrain/gray/%s00%d.ras',imageName, imageName, imgINumber);
elseif imgINumber < 100
    imgIFile = sprintf('C:\sequence01_caltrain_gray\caltrain/gray/%s0%d.ras',imageName, imageName, imgINumber);
end
if imgPNumber < 10
    imgPFile = sprintf('C:\sequence01_caltrain_gray\caltrain\gray/%s00%d.ras',imageName, imageName, imgPNumber);
elseif imgPNumber < 100
    imgPFile = sprintf('C:\sequence01_caltrain_gray\caltrain\gray/%s0%d.ras',imageName, imageName, imgPNumber);
end
imgI = double(imread(imgIFile));
imgP = double(imread(imgPFile));
imgI = imgI(:,1:352);
imgP = imgP(:,1:352);
```

but error:

Error using ==> imread
Can't open file "C:" for reading;
you may not have read permission.

i need solution for this
thanks

Comment: Get yourself read permissions for that file? :-)

Comment: you have `imageName` twice in your `sprintf` arguments.  Remove the `;` on your `sprintf` commands to make sure you have the correct string.

Answer (score 1):

Either double your backslashes or replace all the backslashes with slashes in your `sprintf` calls.